# Removing multiple delimiters between outside delimiters on each line

Tags: regex, string, csv, awk, sed

Using awk or sed in a bash script, I need to remove comma separated delimiters that are located between an inner and outer delimiter. The problem is that wrong values ends up in the wrong columns, where only 3 columns are desired.

For example, I want to turn this:

```
2020/11/04,Test Account,569.00
2020/11/05,Test,Account,250.00
2020/11/05,More,Test,Accounts,225.00
```

Into this:

```
2020/11/04,Test Account,569.00
2020/11/05,Test Account,250.00
2020/11/05,More Test Accounts,225.00
```

I've tried to use a few things, testing regex:
But I cannot find a solution to only select the commas in order to remove.

[image: regexr sample]

Comment: Nobody has suggested you fix the upstream process that is generating the incorrect CSV data.

Comment: There are bunch of answers using regex here so it is good idea to keep this tag to enhance search capability of this question

Comment: Thanks anubhav sir for adding the tag, OP has stated its a regex question not sure why tag is being removed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
awk -F, '{ printf "%s,",$1;for (i=2;i<=NF-2;i++) { printf "%s ",$i };printf "%s,%s\n",$(NF-1),$NF }' file
```

Using awk, print the first comma delimited field and then loop through the rest of the field up to the last but 2 field printing the field followed by a space. Then for the last 2 fields print the last but one field, a comma and then the last field.

Answer (score 8):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk -v OFS=, '{
     match($0,/([^,]*),(.*),([^,]*)/,a)
     gsub(/,/," ",a[2])
     print a[1], a[2], a[3]
}' file
2020/11/04,Test Account,569.00
2020/11/05,Test Account,250.00
2020/11/05,More Test Accounts,225.00
```

or with any awk:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    {
        n = split($0,a)
        gsub(/^[^,]*,|,[^,]*$/,"")
        gsub(/,/," ")
        print a[1], $0, a[n]
    }
' file
2020/11/04,Test Account,569.00
2020/11/05,Test Account,250.00
2020/11/05,More Test Accounts,225.00
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -F',' -lane 'print join ",", $F[0], "@F[1 .. ($#F-1)]", $F[-1];' in.csv
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F','` : Split into `@F` on comma, rather than on whitespace.

`$F[0]` : first element of the array `@F` (= first comma-delimited value).
`$F[-1]` : last element of `@F`.
`@F[1 .. ($#F-1)]` : elements of `@F` between the second from the start and the second from the end, inclusive.
`"@F[1 .. ($#F-1)]"` : the above elements, joined on blanks into a string.
`join ",", ...` : join the LIST "`...`" on a comma, and return the resulting string.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Answer (score 7):

```
perl -pe 's{,\K.*(?=,)}{$& =~ y/,/ /r}e' file
```

```
sed -e ':a' -e 's/\(,[^,]*\),\([^,]*,\)/\1 \2/; t a' file
```

```
awk '{$1=$1","; $NF=","$NF; gsub(/ *, */,","); print}' FS=, file
```

```
awk '{for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) $i=(i>2 && i<NF ? " " : ",") $i} 1' FS=, OFS= file
```

Answer (score 6):

`awk` doesn't support look arounds, we could have it by using `match` function of `awk`; using that could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
match($0,/,.*,/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
  gsub(/,/," ",val)
  print substr($0,1,RSTART) val substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH-1)
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 6):

Yet another `perl`

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?:^[^,]*,|,[^,]*$)(*SKIP)(*F)|,/ /g' ip.txt
2020/11/04,Test Account,569.00
2020/11/05,Test Account,250.00
2020/11/05,More Test Accounts,225.00
```

- `(?:^[^,]*,|,[^,]*$)` matches first/last field along with the comma character

  - `(*SKIP)(*F)` this would prevent modification of preceding regexp
- `|,` provide `,` as alternate regexp to be matched for modification

With `sed` (assuming `\n` is supported by the implementation, otherwise, you'll have to find a character that cannot be present in the input)

```
sed -E 's/,/\n/; s/,([^,]*)$/\n\1/; y/,/ /; y/\n/,/'
```

- `s/,/\n/; s/,([^,]*)$/\n\1/` replace first and last comma with newline character
- `y/,/ /` replace all comma with space
- `y/\n/,/` change newlines back to comma

Answer (score 1):

A similar answer to [Timur's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64787367/7552), in awk

```sh
awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
    function join(start, stop, sep,     str, i) {
        str = $start
        for (i = start + 1; i <= stop; i++) {
            str = str sep $i
        }
        return str
    }
    { print $1, join(2, NF-1, " "), $NF }
' file.csv
```

It's a shame awk doesn't ship with a join function builtin